# What is the meaning of "down by the creek"?

Tags: meaning

I am reading a book, and one sentence which reads:

> he lived in the trailer **down by the** creek

But I cannot understand "down by".

Comment: ***Creek:***  - narrow area of water that flows into the land from the sea, a lake, etc. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/creek

Comment: Hi I know what is the meaning of creek as well as trailer. But, I do not know the meaning of "down by the x".

Comment: "Down by the [...]" is a regional expression. It's not standard English. It means exactly the same thing as "by the [...]."

Comment: Sounds pretty standard to me (American).  We can and do say "up on the mountain", "down to the ocean", "down the road", and so on.  "Down by the river, I shot my baby..."  Stylistically redundant, perhaps, but definitely standard usage.

Comment: Note that water seeks the lowest possible level, so bodies of water (including static ones, like ponds and lakes, and flowing ones, like creeks and rivers) are typically at a lower altitude than the surrounding countryside. Therefore, **down** might simply mean **down**, as in, "If you go down the street [downhill], you'll find a creek; that's where he lived." Compare: "I saw a bird building a nest up by the chimney."

Answer (score 4):

In [R Cowan's 'The Teacher's Grammar of English: A Course Book and Reference Guide'](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WCCk829jmzUC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=preposition+%2B+preposition+Cowan&source=bl&ots=iISRx1dxmr&sig=WLCWpsxCqrQmtt5snoGOVdqhn8Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDxebUsufOAhUFrxoKHV6aASIQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=preposition%20%2B%20preposition%20Cowan&f=false) (Chapter 8: Positions of Occurrence ... p150 Preposition + Preposition Combinations) is found:

> Sequences made up of two prepositions, such as *from behind* and *down
>   to*, occur frequently.... The first preposition can often be followed
>   by [any of] a number of others. For example, *from* occurs freely with
>   prepositions such as *behind, inside* and *beside*, [while] *down*
>   occurs freely with prepositions such as *beside, around* and *by*.
>
> He took the package from *behind / inside / beside / [on top of] /
>   [underneath]* the box and gave it to her.
>
> She wandered down *beside / around / by* the river.

The semantics involved is rather complex.

(a) As @Scott says in a comment, the preposition + prepositional phrase construct (down by ...) may well be taken literally, 'beside the creek, down where it flows through its valley'.

(b) Another less literal sense is given by [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/down):

> **down** adverb (FAR)
>
> ​
>   *down* B1 used, especially with prepositions, to emphasize that a place is at some distance from you or from somewhere considered to be
>   central:
>
> I'll meet you down at the gym after work.
>
> He has a house down by the harbour.
>
> I'm going down to the shop to buy some milk.

(The 'adverb' classification is one I'd reject.)

(c) As RMac says, a largely bleached sense is also in use, probably [via] a colloquial / lyrical development from the second sense above:

> 'Gonna lay down my sleepy head ... Down by the riverside ...'
>
> 'Down by yon flowery garden my love and I we first did meet.' / *Down
>   by the Salley Gardens*, a poem by William Butler Yeats
>
> 'Down by the Station in Kirkwood, Missouri'

While semantically bleached, this usage adds a poetic and/or friendly feel.

But none of these usages can be labelled non-standard, which term [F. Parker and K. Riley, in *Linguistics for Non-Linguists*, 1994](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/nonstandterm.htm) define:

> ... a nonstandard dialect does draw negative attention to itself; that
>   is, educated people might judge the speaker of such a dialect as
>   socially inferior, lacking education, and so on. A nonstandard dialect
>   can thus be characterized as having socially marked forms, such as
>   ain't. A socially marked form is one that causes the listener to form
>   a negative social judgment of the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

"Down by the [...]" is a regional expression. It's not standard English. It means exactly the same thing as "by the [...]."

Comment: Could you please add supporting material for your claim that 'down by the river' (etc) is non-standard? I'm inclined to disagree. And it can certainly have the meaning 'down [the lane, etc] and by the river' as well as the largely bleached reading for 'down'. The book 'Down by the River' by Grace Hallworth published in 1996 was shortlisted for the Kate Greenaway Medal the following year.

Comment: There is no such thing as supporting material that something isn't something else. Rather, I'd instead challenge anyone who disagrees with producing references that it is. The title of a fictional book (or even a non-fictional one, for that matter) can be still be considered nonstandard because authors often intentionally use nonstandard language in an effort to emulate the dialect of a specific region or culture.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  What about a music video with 3.4 million views on YouTube https://youtu.be/lbq4G1TjKYg PJ Harvey's *Down by the water*

Comment: Again, authors will frequently use idiosyncratic or dialectic language in an effort to emulate the speech patterns of a given person or culture. This does not mean their uses conform to standard rules.

Comment: I've found the usage given in R Cowan's 'The Teacher's Grammar of English: A Course Book and Reference Guide'. Grammars flag or omit  non-standard usages. // Dictionaries often add 'non-standard' caveats.

Comment: As a resource targeting English language learners (that is, ESL students), "The Teacher's Grammar of English" does not target an understanding of standard English. The point of my response is that you will see this phrase commonly used in specific dialectic regions and *not* in other dialectic regions in general. I highly doubt that, regardless of whether I'm wrong or right, any academic study has been done on the matter.

Comment: Yes there's material that can disprove an assertion, for example no hit on google book, or references that discuss the point, or in this case a note in a dictionary that says " regional".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/197673)

Comment: I clearly stated what the expression means in my answer. No one replying to this question can possibly assign any meaning to the word "down" in this usage case because it doesn't mean anything at all. The point in emphasizing that this is a nonstandard use case is entirely relevant because *it is* and because someone who does not speak English natively and who doesn't live in an area where this phrase is used colloquially might become very confused attempting to mete out the meaning of this meaningless word.

Comment: While it may not be *necessary* to say down, its not "non-standard."  Rivers, creeks, etc. are usually "down" i.e. lower in elevation. So frequently instead of just "by the river" people say "down by the river." And frequently instead of just "on the mountain" or "on the hill" they say "up on the mountain / hill."  How is that "non-standard"?

Comment: @R Mac. Unfortunately The Cambridge dictionary both agrees and disagrees with you. It depends how you define the use of "down" If is "to the creek" as in "down the pub" you are correct and they state it's use is non standard. However if you define the use of down, in this case as, Along = at a particular place on a road, river, etc; then it is standard English.

Comment: @Brad I don't follow what you mean. The word "along" doesn't appear in the phrase under scrutiny at all.

Comment: @R Mac. If you consult the CED it gives one of the meanings of "down" as "along".

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer:  down by = next to

Answer (score 0):

> **Q. What is the meaning of “down by the creek”?**

> **A. “along the creek”** *along preposition (AT A PARTICULAR PLACE)*

> **at a particular place on a road, river, etc.**

As much as I admire some of the eloquent arguments proposed by my peers. The Cambridge English Dictionary **simply puts the the meaning of down as along** They also think it is Standard English.

Whilst down used as the preposition (TO) is classified as non standard in the UK

> I went down the pub with my mates.

**down preposition (ALONG)** REF [C.E.F.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/down)

> We drove down the highway as far as Atlanta.

> Her office is down the corridor on the right.

> They sailed the boat down the river (= towards the sea)

**down preposition (TO)**

> **UK not standard** to:

**along preposition** (AT A PARTICULAR PLACE) Ref [C.E.F.](http://art.taobao.com/add_cart_succeed.htm?_input_charset=gb18030&spm=2013.1.20140002.d2.undefined)

> at a particular place on a road, river, etc.:

Example

> Somewhere along this road there's a garage.